# How do I run some code for every import at runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Is there a way to have some specific code run for every import statement or dynamic import I have in my application?

For example, I want to check if an import is undefined and then throw an error.

Not sure if this is even possible.

What I'm looking for is something like:

```
import { ObjectOrUndefined } from 'stuff'

if (typeof ObjectOrUndefined === 'undefined') {
    doStuff();
}

...
```

This, but I want to write this code in one place and it should be applied to all files throughout the app.
The above checking for undefined is an example, I want to perform other operations on the imports too.

I'm using webpack and not sure how to move forward.

Comment: Are you having a problem with this or is it just theoretical? Webpack should automatically be throwing errors if an import is undefined.

Comment: @Tim I'm looking for a way to have some code run for every import. the `undefined` check is an example. Edited the question to specify it's an example.